# WebAPI MVC 6 Blank page

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

To host the WebAPI through kestrel, when I run web.cmd as administrator through command prompt, it runs fine.
But when I run it as other user, I get the error as in the below screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I for some reason had to restart the system. When I tried again it was working fine.
But then came the next issue.

I had hosted the webapi on IIS with name "WoApi" under "Default Web Site".
When I tried to access
http://localhost/woapi/api/Aspnet_Role
I got blank page.

Then I checked the stdout.log file. It had the below contents:

Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:20822
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kXVX.jpg)
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/woapi/api/Aspnet_Role
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0.0187ms 404

So, then I tried with 
http://localhost:20822/api/Aspnet_Role
and it worked.

But the port number keeps on changing every-time I restart the server. 
How to keep a fix address?

Comment: It can't find your database, without more info it's impossible for anyone to help. Can you show your connection string?

Comment: Also, please post error messages as text and not images. It's impossible to search on and images can easily disappear.